# How to style Tabs TabStrip border bottom

Tags: tabs, nativescript

By default nativescript Tab TabStrip has a blue border-bottom at the active item. How do i go about changing to color of this blue bottom border ?

I have already tried styling Tabs as per documentation link below in the styling section:

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/tabs

Answer (score 1):

figured this out. I had to change the accent color App_Resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a special nativescript CSS property **highlight-color** for this.

Here is an example:

```
Tabs TabStrip {
    background-color: #fff;
    highlight-color: #f00; // Here you can write your color code 
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is an example from the Playground app: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=hhPr9s&_ga=2.8323127.464253737.1575620904-1702602123.1572291235

Here is an official blog post from the Nativescript team about introducing the Tabs component, i hope it will help: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/tabs-and-bottomnavigation-nativescripts-two-new-components